# How to pass record id into hyperlink in radgrid?

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I've a radgrid and rendering a hyperlink column. I want to pass the id of the record into the url for the hyperlink. How can I do this?

I have this

```
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" HeaderText="Edit" UniqueName="Edit">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="~/Edit.aspx?Id=need_to_bind_id_here">Edit Details</asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
```

There is an ID column which is generated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Edit.aspx?Id="+Eval("RecordIDFieldName") %>'>Edit Details</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: that renders the hyperlink's url to http://localhost:50686/WEB/Edit.aspx?Id=<%# Eval("MRUploadID") %>

Comment: if i just use navigateurl='<%# Eval("MRUploadID") %>' the id comes out. When I try navigateurl='edit.aspx?id=<%# Eval("MRUploadID") %>' to build the url then it comes out as a shown above, a literal string.

Comment: How to apply the same in <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn NavigateUrl=""></telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>